# Checking String Values in Java

Tags: java, string, substring

Im trying to find if the first two letters of a string are "hi". If it does it shold return true, and if not it should return false. I used substring to find the values of the given string, but when the condition comes up true it isn't returning true. I must not be understanding something about Java, which Im new to.

Here is my code:

```
class Main {
    public boolean startHi(String str) {


        String str1 = str.substring(0,1);
        String str2 = str.substring(1,2);

        if(str1=="h" && str2=="i"){
            return true;
        }
        if(str!="hi" || str.length()<=2){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Main().startHi("hi ho"));
        System.out.println(new Main().startHi("hi"));
        System.out.println(new Main().startHi("howhi"));
    }
}
```

The string starts with "hi" and it sees that, but it returns false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not returning `true` because you have to compare strings with the `equals()` method.

```
    if("h".equals(str1) && "i".equals(str2)){
        return true;
    }
```

If you use `==` to compare objects it will check if it's the same object so it checks if the memory addresses of the objects are the same.

The string class overrides the `equals()` method to check for content.

If you're creating a string like this

```
String s1 = "Hi";
```

Java will put `"Hi"` in the so called string literal pool
so if you are creating a second string

```
 String s2 = "Hi";
```

Java will not create a second Object but will refer to the "Hi" in the string literal pool.

Now you could do compare the two strings like `s1 == s2` and it would be `true`
because the two references `s1` and `s2` point to the same object.

But what the `substring()` method does is `new String("xyz")` and if you declare a string like this a new object will be created and the comparison with `==` will return false because the two references obviously don't point on the same object.

Comment: That works, thank you. You cant use the comparison operators for just strings in Java or?

Comment: I edited my answer. Hope this helps you a little

Comment: It does very much, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [String.startsWith(String prefix)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String))

```
public boolean startHi(String str) {
    return str.startsWith("hi");
}
```

So after all you probably don't need your own `startHi()` method, but can use standard Java API.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
 if(str1.equals("h") && str2.equals("i")) //equals use instead of (==) Operator.
```

instead Of

```
if(str1 =="h"  && str2 == "i")
```

OR

```
if(str.startsWith("hi") // this will also works
```